# Can two structs reference each other? - Julia

Tags: julia

I have a struct that includes a field of the same type, which I cannot assign at creation.
Julia does not seem to like the following. (It coughs up a circular reference complaint.) I intend this to boil the problem down to its essentials

```
mutable struct Test
    test:: Union{Test,Nothing}
end
t1 = Test(nothing)
t2 = Test(nothing)
t1.test = t2
t2.test = t1
```

1. What is the right way to achieve this? (E.g., how can I point to my partner, who can point to me as his partner?)
2. Separately, is the above currently the right way to have an initially "null" field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you propose is a correct way to have initially `nothing` field.

Alternatively you can do something like:

```
julia> mutable struct Test
           test::Test
           Test(t::Test) = new(t)
           Test() = new()
       end

julia> t1 = Test()
Test(#undef)

julia> t2 = Test()
Test(#undef)

julia> t1.test = t2
Test(#undef)

julia> t2.test = t1
Test(Test(Test(#= circular reference @-2 =#)))
```

where you have temporarily `#undef` field.

See also [Incomplete Initialization](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#Incomplete-Initialization) section of the Julia Manual.

#### Edit

An example of circular reference with a standard `Vector{Any}`:

```
julia> x = Any[]
Any[]

julia> push!(x, x)
1-element Vector{Any}:
 1-element Vector{Any}:#= circular reference @-1 =#
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about the core of the question (i.e., the circular reference problem)? Or are you suggesting that, despite the unusual output, no problem lurks there?

Comment: This is just a standard way to display values that have circular references. You can define custom display for your type if you like to avoid this. I have added an edit showing you that this is a normal thing.